# Why does push from parse.com reach only one device?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, push-notification

I try to implement push. I have the following code

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        if application.applicationState != UIApplicationState.Background {
        // In that case, we skip tracking here to avoid double counting the app-open.

        let preBackgroundPush = !application.respondsToSelector("backgroundRefreshStatus")
        let oldPushHandlerOnly = !self.respondsToSelector("application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:")
        var pushPayload = false
        if let options = launchOptions {
            pushPayload = options[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] != nil
        }
        if (preBackgroundPush || oldPushHandlerOnly || pushPayload) {
            PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions)
        }
    }
    if application.respondsToSelector("registerUserNotificationSettings:") {
        let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    } else {
        let types : UIRemoteNotificationType =  [.Badge, .Alert, .Sound]
        application.registerForRemoteNotificationTypes(types)
    }
  }
```

for subscription I use following code in `viewDidLoad`

```
let currentInstallation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
    currentInstallation.addUniqueObject("Giants", forKey: "channels")
    currentInstallation.saveInBackground()
```

The problem is that when I send push only one device receives it. For testing purposes I connected second device to Xcode but it doesnt receive push messages.

For setup I used development certificate.

Is there any limitations on development certificates or I do something wrong ?

Comment: What do you see in your Push Delivery Report on Parse ?

Comment: It reports about one sent push

Comment: So you sent a single Push and you expect it to be delivered to two devices ??

Comment: yes, because I target all devices

Comment: sure, but the Push report clearly shows your notification is delivered to only one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things you should keep in mind here.

1. It's good practice to sign the device up for push notifications in the App Delegate. By no means is you method wrong, just usually you do it in the App Delegate (See the Parse docs)
2. You cannot use the simulator to receive push notifications. You need to have an actual device.

Now, how to see where something may have gone wrong.

1. In you Prase dashboard, you should see a class called installations. In there you should have both the devices. If you only see one device that means that only the first device was registered. To fix that you can move the code to the App Delegate, re-run the program or set a breakpoint to see if it even reaches this code.
2. Check the Installation file for the channels. You should see a column called channels, where you should have Giants for both devices. If not something went wrong here and you're only targeting one device. To fix this error you can simply delete the app or manually add the `Channels` key
3. Another possible error you may have is that you declined the permission to send push notifications. Make sure this is enabled on the second device. To do that go to *Settings -> Notifications -> "YOUR APP NAME"* -> Toggle **ALLOW NOTIFICATIONS** to on. and select Banners for example.
4. Check that you  have the correct provisioning profile installed in Xcode that has both the devices. **This is the correct answer. The asker figured this out while in chat. Updating the provisioning profile with both devices fixed the problem for him.**

Hope that helps, Julian

Comment: So you have both devices signed up in the Installations?

Comment: Yes, I see both devices in Parse installations table, I checked it by comparing device tokens inside app and inside table.

Comment: How do you send the push? Code or panel?

Comment: I tried both - inside panel and inside app with the following code https://s.mail.ru/joWYsZ2Pbfgq/img-2015-11-18-21-33-14.png

Comment: both times only one device receives message

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95480/discussion-between-julian-e-and-alexey-k).

Comment: Try closing the app in both devices and sending the push.